# ASA 5525-X PAT only for one IP subnet

Tags: cisco, routing, nat, firewall

Can an ASA 5525-X dynamically PAT one IP subnet of private addresses (from inside port to outside port) and simultaneously pass another subnet through without PAT?

I have a public IP address on the outside interface and another public IP subnet behind the firewall.

- outside interface - 198.98.9.1/24
- ISP gateway 198.98.9.2
- Private IP - 192.168.1.1/24. The inside interface connects to another router at 192.168.1.2/24.  That router has:

  - Private interface 191.167.1.1/24
  - Public interface 187.87.7.1/27

My goal is to dynamically PAT only IP subnet 191.167.1.0/24 and not IP subnet 187.87.7.0/27.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 198.98.9.1 255.255.255.0

!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 

ASA(config)#object network PUBLIC
ASA(config-obj)#subnet 187.87.7.0 255.255.255.224

ASA(config)#object network PRIVATE
ASA(config-obj)#subnet 191.167.1.0 255.255.255.0

ASA(config)#object network INTERNET
ASA(config-obj)#subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0

ASA(config)#nat (inside,outside) source dynamic PRIVATE interface

ASA(config)#nat (inside,outside) source static PUBLIC PUBLIC destination static INTERNET INTERNET
```

Routing between router and asa is simple. I have default route on cisco router forward to inside asa address. And on asa default route forward to ISP address. On other direction on asa I have two static routes forward to public and private ip subnet.

Can something like this work?

Comment: I must admit that I don't quite understand the problem, but I believe this can be done fairly easily with network objects :)

Comment: "*can it do X*": YES. **HOW** to do it is not the question you've asked. (and that depends on the version you're running -- old nat vs. new nat syntax. 'tho a 5525-x is almost certainly going to be 8.3+)

Comment: As @RickyBeam pointed out, the simple answer is "YES", it can.  But if you want more help than that, you should give us some example IPs and ask us what you want translated where, and when.  I'm sure someone will be able to write out the required syntax.

Comment: Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I cant believe nobody have an idea for required syntax ?!

Comment: Hi @Blabla, welcome to the Network Engineering Stack Exchange.  I would suggest posting the rest of your (sanitized) configuration.  What you already posted, syntax wise, should do exactly what you are asking.  If it isn't, then you must have something else configured which is preventing it, and if you post the rest of your configuration, someone will be able to help.

Comment: PAT is really made up. The RFCs use NAPT for what some people call PAT. See _[RFC 2663, IP Network Address Translator (NAT) Terminology and Considerations, Section 4.1.2 Network Address Port Translation (NAPT)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2663#section-4.1.2)_: "_NAPT extends the notion of translation one step further by also translating transport identifier (e.g., TCP and UDP port numbers, ICMP query identifiers). This allows the transport identifiers of a number of private hosts to be multiplexed into the transport identifiers of a single external address._" There is more in the RFC.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to specify a NO-NAT for your 187.87.7.0/27 but I don't know why.

Simply having "nat (inside,outside) source dynamic PRIVATE interface" will dynamically PAT your 191.167.1.0/24 to 198.98.9.1

Then traffic traversing your inside to outside will not hit the NAT statement therefore pass through without NAT?

Isn't this what you want?